# Using tkinter/grid to put autoscrolled Treeview in a frame

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, autoscroll

I'm hopelessly trying to put a autoscroll Treeview in a frame using grid. No matter what I do, the scrollbars do not appear. On the other hand, if I use place, it works. But since everything in my form is put using grid, I'd like to keep it that way.

so, this code works:

```
try:
   from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
   from tkinter import *
try:
   import ttk
   py3 = False
except ImportError:
   import tkinter.ttk as ttk
   py3 = True


class OperationWindow(Frame):
   def __init__(self, master):
       Frame.__init__(self, master)
       self.master = master
       self.frTable = Frame(master, width=920, height=250)
       self.frTable.grid(row=0, column=0)
       self.frTable.grid_propagate(0)

       self.Table = ScrolledTreeView(self.frTable)
       self.Table.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=0.96, 
          relwidth=1.0)
       self.Table['columns'] = g_list_col_names

class AutoScroll(object):
   def __init__(self, master):
       try:
           vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(master, orient='vertical', command=self.yview)
       except:
           pass
       hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(master, orient='horizontal', command=self.xview)

       try:
           self.configure(yscrollcommand=self._autoscroll(vsb))
       except:
           pass
       self.configure(xscrollcommand=self._autoscroll(hsb))

       self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

       try:
           vsb.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='ns')
       except:
           pass
       hsb.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='ew')

       master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
       master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

       if py3:
           methods = Pack.__dict__.keys() | Grid.__dict__.keys() \
                 | Place.__dict__.keys()
       else:
           methods = Pack.__dict__.keys() + Grid.__dict__.keys() \
                 + Place.__dict__.keys()

       for meth in methods:
           if meth[0] != '_' and meth not in ('config', 'configure'):
               setattr(self, meth, getattr(master, meth))

   @staticmethod
   def _autoscroll(sbar):
       def wrapped(first, last):
           first, last = float(first), float(last)
           if first <= 0 and last >= 1:
               sbar.grid_remove()
           else:
               sbar.grid()
           sbar.set(first, last)
       return wrapped

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.master)


def _create_container(func):
   def wrapped(cls, master, **kw):
       container = ttk.Frame(master)
       return func(cls, container, **kw)
   return wrapped


class ScrolledTreeView(AutoScroll, ttk.Treeview):
   @_create_container
   def __init__(self, master, **kw):
       ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, master, **kw)
       AutoScroll.__init__(self, master)


def main():
   global g_list_col_names
   g_list_col_names = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
    '10','11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
   root = Tk()
   master = OperationWindow(root)
   root.mainloop()
main()
```

and it stops if I change this one line:

```
self.Table.place(relx=0.0, rely=0.0, relheight=0.96, relwidth=1.0)
```

to this:

```
self.Table.grid(sticky='ew')
```

Comment: please create a [mcve] instead of just disjointed blocks of code. You also need to show the `AutoScroll` class, or show us where you're importing it from.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. I have updated the AutoScroll. I'll look into providing the minimal, complete, and verifiable example, as you requested.

Comment: I've provided the minimal, complete and verifiable example, as requested. As you can test for yourself, it does work with the place.

Comment: This code still doesn't run. `local variable 'g_list_col_names' referenced before assignment`

Comment: There is some indention issues in your code and on my end `@_create_container` is invalid. Please correct indention. Also `g_list_col_names` should be deleted from `def main():` as you do not assign it to anything on the first line but do on the 2nd of the main function.

Comment: corrected. Should be working now. A apologize, this is my first post here.

Comment: why are you calling `grid()` but not specifying a row or column?

Comment: it's in the row=0, column=0 position. But a valid point, style-wise. I'll correct that. Thanks!

Comment: You method of writing classes and functions is strange to me. Why are you using `@_create_container`. It is not something I am use to seeing so I would like to know the reason.

Comment: It just looks like you are doing things the hard way. When I write something up like this it looks nothing like your code. Is it a style that is more prominent in other coding languages?

Comment: "ScrolledTreeView", "create_container", and "AutoScroll" were automatically written by the PAGE gui builder. I would have done it differently. Nevertheless, I wonder why it's only working with place.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? It seems like the first thing you should do is add some print statements to see why it's hiding the scrollbar when you think it shouldn't. It looks to me like it's working the way it's supposed to -- there's nothing in the tree so it hides the scrollbar.

Comment: once I add stuff to the tree, nothing happens as well.

Comment: Please show that. The way autoscroll is designed to work is that it hides the scrollbars unless there's something that is scrollable, and your code doesn't have anything that's scrollable. I also strongly recommend you reduce your [mcve] down even further to only work with a couple columns and a vertical scrollbar. Once you get that working, then you can focus on horizontal scrolling which is a little trickier with the treeview widget.

Comment: In fact, the smartest thing would be for you to first create a program that doesn't do the autoscroll, but has proper scrollbars. Get that working first, and then switch to trying to make the autoscroll work so that you're not trying to solve several problems at once.

Comment: thanks, Bryan, let me try your last suggestion before doing anything else.